# Splitting html string after so many words

Tags: php

I have a string that if it is longer than lets say 10 words, I want to split it into two parts. The second part will be included else-where after a 'more' link.

The string will hold html tags too though. 
For an example the string could be:

```
<p>This is just a test string with more words than the <strong>amount allow</strong> before split, blah blah blah</p>
```

So in the case I would want:

```
$string[0] // <p>This is just a test string with more words than</p>;
$string[1] // <p>the <strong>amount allow</strong> before split, blah blah blah</p>;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see an easy answer to this due to the HTML constraint. Imagine that the whole text is wrapped in a span.. you could only split it if you also closed the tag in the snippet and adding the opening to the remainder..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I've had the same issues. I solved this in letting my news-writers allow to use "[intro]...[/intro]"-Tags within their texts. Then I parsed the tags with a regex.

If the cutting should be done automatically without using special tags, it's a bit more difficult. You could use the `substr()`-function. But then you would have problems with the html-tags. Therefore I would cut them as well with something like: `substr(strip_tags($text), 0, 50)`. This would allow 50 chars to be displayed, exclusive the html-tags.

Maybe this can help you :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not trivial, but here's an idea:

- Iterate through the string, character by character
- keep at least these state variables:

  - `$inTag` – whether you're inside a tag
  - `$inAttribute` – whether you're inside a tag attribute (where ">" doesn't end the tag)
  - `$currentTagSoFar` – all the characters of the current tag. Would start with "s", then "st", "str", etc., until "strong"
  - `$openedTags` – stack variable where you put the currently opened tags (push when you find an opening tag, pop when you find a closing one)
  - `$wordsSoFar` – the number of words you've found so far
  - maybe also `$insideComment`, depending on how thorough you want to be
- When you reach your target number of words, pop the tags from the stack and add the remaning closing tags to the string.